# Trying to make some type of IF mySQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to make an SQL statement that has a type of IF statement inside of it. This is my current statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, p.FrameNumber 
        FROM BikeStock b LEFT JOIN Purchase p 
               on b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber 
        WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'";
```

I Want to combine the above statement with the text below but not sure how.

IF PurchaseID within the BikeStock table has a value above 0, it will select a different framenumber.

Help would be really appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
SELECT b.BikeCode, IF(b.PurchaseID > 0, 
        p.FrameNumber, b.FrameNumber) AS FrameNumber 
    FROM BikeStock b 
    LEFT JOIN Purchase p on b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber 
    WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'
```

P.S. don't forget to escape `$bikecode` for SQL injections.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work but thank you. Maybe, i am not to sure why and is your IF statement saying if Frame number is bigger than 0 it will be processed?

Comment: you can try IFNULL instead of IF and switch places of arguments

Comment: i'm confused, so IFNULL(b.purchaseID, p.FrameNumber, b.FrameNumber) As FrameNumber

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, 
    CASE WHEN b.purchasreID > 0 THEN p.other_framenumber ELSE p.FrameNumber END AS FrameNumber
FROM BikeStock b LEFT JOIN Purchase p 
ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber
WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'
```

Apart from that, consider [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you for your other. I don't really understand how you are doing that. As i don't have a field called other_framenumber. Maybe i explained what i wanted above incorrectly. I want it when a framenumber is selected i want it to make sure that framenumber does not have a purchaseID and if it does i want it to select another framenumber.

Comment: "another framenumber" being what?

Comment: Within my BikeStock table i have 4 framenumbers that have the bikecode 123. I want it if someone has already purchased one framenumber it will choose another one of framenumbers. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand and do not know enough about your database structure to help you further. Change `p.other_framenumber` to the value you want.